# caffe installation stuck at make pycaffe

Tags: python, deep-learning, ubuntu-16.04, caffe, pycaffe

I am trying to install caffe on Linux 16.04. I am following this link: http://hanzratech.in/2015/07/27/installing-caffe-on-ubuntu.html and done with following steps:

```
sudo apt-get install libprotobuf-dev libleveldb-dev libsnappy-dev libopencv-dev libhdf5-serial-dev protobuf-compiler
sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends libboost-all-dev
sudo apt-get install libatlas-base-dev
sudo apt-get install the python-dev
sudo apt-get install libgflags-dev libgoogle-glog-dev liblmdb-dev
git clone http://github.com/BVLC/caffe.git
cd caffe
```

uncommented `CPU_ONLY := 1` in `Makefile.config`

```
make all
make test
make runtest
```

but installation freezes at next step i.e.

```
make pycaffe
```

after single line output

```
CXX/LD -o python/caffe/_caffe.so python/caffe/_caffe.cpp
```

Comment: Use this guide from BVLC https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/wiki/Ubuntu-16.04-or-15.10-Installation-Guide . I installed Caffe using this link on Ubuntu 16.04 just yesterday.

Comment: @HarshWardhan thanks. I just solved the issue and it seem that it was a memory overflow issue (I increased the RAM and it worked fine) due to which the installation was stuck (sadly, without any output).

Comment: In my case, I had to make a swap (and I was not able in the beginning due to full disk space, so that might have also been an issue for `make pycaffe` not working